# How to not queue new build if no available agents

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am wondering if there is a way in TFS to prohibit new builds from queuing if there are no agents online to run it.

I am asking this because we have a build job that kicks off every 15 minutes. Occasionally our test agents will become disconnected and unavailable. This causes a bunch of build jobs to stack up in the Queue.

Is there a way to tell an automated TFS build definition to not start if all agents are offline? I know we can limit the amount of time one can run before it stops but that only works once its started. If it cant kick off because no agents are available, then this guard will not work and the queue gets backed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way to do this. When a job add to the queue, the build agent downloads a listener OAuth token and uses it to listen to the job queue.

Periodically, the agent checks to see if a new job request has been posted for it in the job queue in Azure Pipelines/TFS. When a job is available, the agent downloads the job as well as a job-specific OAuth token. This token is generated by Azure Pipelines/TFS for the scoped identity specified in the pipeline. That token is short lived and is used by the agent to access resources (e.g., source code) or modify resources (e.g., upload test results) on Azure Pipelines or TFS within that job.

More details please take a look at [agent communication with Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#communication)